# Procedurally Referencing Data Across Multiple Sheet in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to dynamically reference data from multiple sheets into multiple cells on one sheet. I'm constantly creating new sheets within the same workbook. I'd like to be able to set it up to where I can easily auto-populate the cells with the data from a new sheet instead of having to rewrite the formula with the new sheet's name.

I'm currently using ='sheetname'!B1 to reference the data from multiple sheets. The problem is when I click and drag the cell to reference a different sheet it changes to ='sheetname'!B2. I've set up the A column with the names of the sheets and tried to figure out a way to reference those as the sheet names but was unsuccessful. Here is a link to a google sheet that shows the problem I'm having:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lVPemberRSKDcHc3ogz4XE_PTgSAO9IYXx5RCmVQ9C8/edit?usp=sharing

I want the cell B2 in "Totals" to reference A2 as the sheet name and then I want to be able to click and drag so that B3 references A3 as the cell name but doesn't change the cell that it is pulling data from on each of the different sheets.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out. You have to use =INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!B12"). Way more simple than I thought it was going to be...